# How to process large text files more efficiently with Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

Problem:

I need to search a huge text file (containing around 1.5 million lines of data) extracting those lines which match a unique ID. I have stored my unique IDs in an array and iterate through the entire file once per array element.

While this method is ok for small arrays, if the array is pretty big it slows down my program considerably as there are so many operations to do.

My array could contain up to 10,000 unique identifiers in the form of:

```
DC888U1
DC888U2
DC888U3 
... 
...
```

and lines in my datafile will always begin with a unique identifier.

```
DC888U1 Apples 0.99 75
DC888U2 Oranges 0.75 1002
DC888U3 Bread 1.35 100
... ... ... ...
... ... ... ...
```

My code below:

```
#array containing identifiers
open (IDENTIFIERS "< keywords.txt") or die "Cannot open file: $!";
    chomp(my @keywords = <IDENTIFIERS>);
close (IDENTIFIERS);

#iterate through the array element by element
foreach my $element (@keywords) {
    open (FH "< inventory.txt") or die "cannot open file: $!";
    while (<FH>) {
        if ($_ =~ /^\Q$element\E/) {
            print $_;
        }
    }
close (FH);
}
```

I've looked at Tie::File to see if that can speed up my processing but have had no luck. I'm wondering is there a way I can cache the lines already printed so that when I pass through the file the next time the amount of data to search through is less each time.

Is there?

Answer (score 4):

The key is to transform your O(N*M) code into O(N+M):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;  # For autodie
use autodie;

die <<ERROR unless @ARGV > 1;
Identifiers file missing.
Usage: $0 identifiers_file [ inventory_file ]
ERROR

my $keywords_re = do {
    my $keywords_file = shift;
    open my $fh, '<', $keywords_file;
    my @keywords = <$fh>;
    chomp @keywords;
    my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, @keywords;
    qr/$re/;
};

while (<>) { print if /^$keywords_re\s/ }
```

An alternative if you are sure your keywords can't contain whitespace inspired by [Sinan Ünür](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100754/sinan-%c3%9cn%c3%bcr)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31562034/49197).

```
my %keywords;
{
    my $keywords_file = shift;
    open my $fh, '<', $keywords_file;
    @keywords{ map s/\s//gr, <$fh> } = (); #/ make syntax highlight happy
};

while (<>) { print if /^(\S+)/ and exists $keywords{$1} }
```

Comment: @Borodin: `perl -E'my $re = "aa|bb"; $re = qr/$re/; say "No it does not, Borodin." unless "abb" =~ /^$re/'`

Answer (score 3):

For most common line lengths, 1.5 million lines of data is not a huge amount. If each line is 1K, you have 1.5GB of data which fit neatly in memory even on my decade old laptop.

Your problem is due to the fact that you process the file over-and-over again for each identifier.

So, if you have 10,000 identifiers, and it takes one second to process the file, your process will still take 3 hours. If it takes one minute to process the file, your method will take 7 days.

Put your 10,000 identifiers in a hash as keys. Then, as you iterate through the file, capture the initial sequence of non-space characters on each line, check if it is a key in the hash; print if it is.

Untested:

```
 my %keywords = map { $_ => undef } @keywords;
 while (my $line = <$in>) {
     my ($id) = ($line =~ /^(\S+)/);
     if (exists $keywords{$id}) {
          print $line;
     }
 }
```

Comment: The `^` anchor is pointless unless you handle the case where the regex doesn't match

Comment: @Borodin I write what I mean. If the identifier is expected to be at the beginning of the line, I write that. The point of the answer is to get rid of the repeated reading of the file ... The OP can handle the rest depending on the whether leading whitespace is allowed on data lines.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for an optimization and this hugely depends on the context.

If you file is sorted (with "sorted" actually meaning "sorted according to your own criteria"), you could decide to waste some disk space and create a new file that contains the same lines padded to have all the same length.

Then you use a binary search on that file to get the line number of at least one of the occurrences of the identifier you're looking for (that's why you need the same line length, the *seek* on the file will not work correctly otherwise).

If the identifiers are unique inside the file, you're done.
If they're not, you just move up one line until the identifier changes and down one line until the identifier changes and you have the interval.

Again: this only works if the file is sorted and the lines have all the same length, but if that's the case, then you're going to see a huge speed improvement. I know because I've done this myself to search inside a 200Mb+ text file :)